# How can I have probability decrease linearly with more dice?

Tags: probability

I'm working on a simplified rpg-system that only use D6 and I want a mechanic for fumble/critical fail.

Depending on how good the player is they have 1-5 dice to roll and they have to beat a difficulty set by the player. I thought it would be fun to have players fail if they roll all 1:s but realised it makes it way too hard to fail if you have 5 dice, and a bit too simple if you have 1. Is there some more linear way of defining critical fails?

This is what I get:

```
Nubmer of Die   Probability of all 1:s
1               16.67%
2               2.78%
3               0.46%
4               0.08%
5               0.01%
```

What I would like(approximately, exact numbers are not that important), I can tweak it with extra rolls etc:

```
Nubmer of Die   Probability:
1               18%
2               15%
3               12%
4               9%
5               6%
```

Of course keeping it simple would be nice ;)

Comment: In your examples the probability *decreases* with the number of dice but your title says "increase:" what is the question, exactly?

Comment: @whuber thx, the probability of not fumbling decreases, but that was not made clear at all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to roll 2D6, but rather than adding the numbers, make the first roll the ten's value and the next the one's value. So if you rolled 2 and 3, you would get 23, not 5.

With this, you now have 36 possible outcomes *each with equal probability*. Since each outcome is roughly 2.8%, you could define failures as rolling equal to or below a certain threshold. So for example, we could have the following:

```
Threshold    Probability
11           0.028
12           0.056
13           0.083
...          ...
21           0.194
22           0.222
etc.
```